# Load in netstandard2.0 libraries to net461 project

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

A quick google says [this is](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md#net-framework-461-supporting-net-standard-20) [possible](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1267), but I can't find out how?

I want to play around with SignalR-Core and service fabric. The latest `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` package is `1.0.0-alpha1-26359` and targets `netstandard2.0`

The current version of ServiceFabric's libraries `5.6.220` (`2.6.220` for the other libraries) target `net45` (I think?.. Anyone know how to quickly check what frameworks a nuget package targets?). From what I'm aware `net45` libraries can run on any framework `>= net45` so that shouldn't be a problem.

My service fabric application project targets `net461` and I'm running VS2017 with whatever the latest update is as of today.

When I try and install the package with `install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR -pre` it says `install-package : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-alpha1-26359 is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-alpha1-26359 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)`

What am I missing here? Is there some csproj trickery I have to do that the powershell script/VS2017 isn't aware of yet? Will this only be a feature when .NET Core 2.0 is released proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Using `VS2017-Update3 (Preview)` made this work fine.</strike>

`VS2017 15.3` includes support for this.